# How to regex match comma separated values in any order?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I am dealing with a log line that contains a comma separated value for a particular field -

```
xyz=,xyz_xyztest_27_jun_2019_2:4000,a_test_case_id-20190624.1:7|431
```

Logging of these comma separated values may happen **in any order**. For example -

```
xyz=,a_test_case_id-20190624.1:7|431,xyz_xyztest_27_jun_2019_2:4000
```

I am trying to write a regex in perl to match these values -

```
=~/^(?=.*xyz=)(?=.*xyz_xyztest_27_jun_2019_2:[\da-f]+)(?=.*a_test_case_id-20190624.1:[\da-f]+\|[\da-f]+)/
```

But this doesn't seem to match. Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: Your pattern only consists of Lookaheads, meaning that it will only match the empty string (AKA, assert the position) that is followed by everything else. Put the parts that you want to capture in capturing groups: `^(?=.*(xyz=))(?=.*(xyz_xyztest_27_jun_2019_2:[\da-f]+))(?=.*(a_test_case_id-20190624\.1:[\da-f]+\|[\da-f]+))`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/6OGEa0/1

Comment: You have provided input, what is desired effect you expect from processing input data?

Comment: Try 2 capturing groups `\G([^\s,=]+)[=:]([^\s,=]*)(?:,|$)` https://regex101.com/r/2zQpBn/1

Answer (score 0):

OP's question is obscure in nature without sample of desired result/output.

Following code assumes that fields separated with `,` and variable/value pairs separated with `=:`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my %hash;
    %hash = split "[,=:]";
    say Dumper(\%hash);
}

__DATA__
xyz=,xyz_xyztest_27_jun_2019_2:4000,a_test_case_id-20190624.1:7|431
xyz=,a_test_case_id-20190624.1:7|431,xyz_xyztest_27_jun_2019_2:4000
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'xyz_xyztest_27_jun_2019_2' => '4000',
          'a_test_case_id-20190624.1' => '7|431',
          'xyz' => ''
        };

$VAR1 = {
          'xyz' => '',
          'xyz_xyztest_27_jun_2019_2' => '4000',
          'a_test_case_id-20190624.1' => '7|431'
        };
```